# How to accumulate the results of readr::read_lines_chunked?

Tags: r, readr

I'm using `readr::read_lines_chunked` in the following way:

```
if(!require(readr)) install.packages("readr", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

mytb <- NULL
read_lines_chunked(file="/tmp/huge.xml", chunk_size=10, callback = function(xml, pos) {
   // extract values from xml into tmp
   if (is.null(mytb)) {
      users <- as_tibble(tmp)
   } else {
      users <- bind_rows(users, as_tibble(tmp)) 
   }
})
```

but this doesn't work as `mytb` always ends up being `null` ... how do you accumulate the results into a tibble?

Comment: The variable names are hard to follow here - the two arguments in the callback function are `xml` and `pos` but then you don't use them, and `tmp` isn't declared before it's used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. This package has a group of callback handlers that wrap the custom handler. So this is how it works:

```
mytb <- read_lines_chunked(file="/tmp/huge.xml", chunk_size=10, callback = DataFrameCallback$new(function(xml, pos) {
   // extract values from xml into tmp
   as_tibble(tmp)
}))
```

Note the `DataFrameCallback$new(...)` decorator and returning the tibble I want to stitch together as `rbind`.